# Django: Formset & unnecessary input fields

Tags: django

I want to update the model_field cancelled with a model_formset. To 'inform' the user, I also want to show the values `first_name, last_name & ticket_reference`. However, that makes it mandatory to include `{{ form.ticket_reference }}` etc. just to hide it in `__init__`. Is there a better approach?

[image: Canceled checkbox & values]

views.py

```
RefundFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        Attendee,
        form=CancelTicketForm,
        extra=0,
    )
    order = Order.objects.get(
        order_reference=order_reference,
    )
    attendee = [{'attendee': attendee} for attendee in order.attendees.all()]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = RefundFormSet(
            request.POST,
            queryset=order.attendees.all(),
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the formset.cleaned_data
            print("FORMSET SUCCESS")
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.save(update_fields=['canceled'])
                print(instance, "SAVED...")
    else:
        form = RefundForm()
        formset = RefundFormSet(
            queryset=order.attendees.all(),
        )
```

forms.py

```
    class CancelTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Attendee
            fields = ['canceled', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'ticket_reference', ]

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['ticket_reference'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['first_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
            self.fields['last_name'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

template.html

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.id }}
        {{ form.canceled }}
        {{ form.first_name.value }}
        {{ form.first_name }}
        {{ form.last_name.value }}
        {{ form.last_name }}
        {{ form.ticket_reference.value }}
        {{ form.ticket_reference }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        {% trans "Refund" %}
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think `{{ form.instance.ticket_reference }}` should work, but you'll have to try yourself.

Comment: It does! Wow thank you. Small change, huge impact :)